# How can one user delete another user's question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I'm curious how [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375464/creating-fluid-layout-with-javascript) got deleted (you'll need sufficient rep on Stack Overflow to see it; screenshot below). It shows that a question by **user1508767** was deleted by **user14377** when it had an answer from user **Random**. Neither of the "userXYZ" accounts is a link, suggesting they've been deleted.

Obviously, mods can delete questions and remove users. I'm just curious about the attribution that **user14377** was the one deleting it...?

[image: Deleted question screenshot]

Comment: And of course, note that post owners can delete questions when there are *no answers*, or just *a single answer whose score is zero or less*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Only diamond moderators and the owners of a post can delete with a single vote.

Users are renamed upon deletion to the userXYZ format, so the user name you're seeing is not the original one.

I suspect that this post was self-deleted by the user, and the user was previously called user14377 and was renamed after deletion to user1508767. The "deleted by ..." notice isn't properly updated to the changed user name and that this causes the discrepancy. This is a guess, but as the number of users that can delete with a single vote is very limited, it seems plausible that it must have been the post owner.

Comment: That theory makes a lot of sense, thank you.

Comment: In fact, I think that user1508767 can be called something like "user14377" if they first register on some small Stack Exchange site without entering a name and then join Stack Overflow - they get a much higher user ID on SO but the autogenerated name is kept.

Comment: Btw, your guess is correct ([the proof](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Astackoverflow.com%2Fusers%2F1508767%2Fuser14377)). The user's original account is on Code Review.

Comment: True, I guess; see [Deleted posts may show wrong user name](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62813/deleted-posts-may-show-wrong-user-name). I figured it might have been related to merged (and deleted) sock puppets too, by then it would have shown "Deleted by owner".

Comment: @Wladimir, I would say that *your* guess was correct: the link of that Google cache refers to `/users/1508767/user14377`. No renaming to some random new number after deletion.

Comment: @Arjan: It isn't random - deleted users are always displayed with the autogenerated name based on their user ID. So if the user ID was 1508767 then he will be displayed as user1508767, even though the original name was user14377 (carried over from Code Review).

Comment: Sure, @Wladimir, but that is what *you* said, right? :-) (Reading Mad's answer made me think it would be some new random number, to get from some number to a new number. But you made very clear that it's really the existing user id. Maybe Mad meant the same thing though. Sorry for the confusion!)